# Box2D coordinate system concepts: PTM_RATIO and retina display

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, physics, retina-display, box2d-iphone

Recently I published a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242708/ptm-ratio-in-retina-display-using-box2d-cocos2d-and-physics-editor) regarding this topic and I received a useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19243276/1533975), but my experimentation points me in a different way that I don’t understamd.

From the answer is clear that we should use the same PTM_RATIO for retina and non-retina devices. However we may double it from iPhone to iPad if we want to show the same portion of the world. In my case I used 50 for iPhone and 100 for iPad because Box2d simulations works better if the bodies are between 0.1 and 10m and the main sprite is about 2m.

I used Physics Editor to build the fixtures using GB2ShapeCache without success for retina devices. Then I decided to feed Box2D coordinates directly and I reached strange conclusions that I would like to clarify.

I created a debug method (independent from any sprite) to draw a single line from 1/3 of screens height to 1/3 of screens wide.

```
- (void)debugGround
{
    // iPad: 1024x768
    // iPhone: 480x320
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;    // unit is points
    b2EdgeShape groundShape;
    b2FixtureDef groundFixtureDef;
    groundFixtureDef.shape = &groundShape;
    groundFixtureDef.density = 0.0;

    b2Vec2 left = b2Vec2(0, winSize.height/3/PTM_RATIO);
    b2Vec2 right = b2Vec2(winSize.width/3/PTM_RATIO, winSize.height/3/PTM_RATIO);
    groundShape.Set(left, right);
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundFixtureDef);
}
```

If Box2D takes coordinates in points and converts them dividing by PTM_RATIO, the result should be the same for iPhone and iPad retina and non retina.

The result for iPad non retina is as expected:

[image]

But for iPhone retina and iPad retina, the fixtures are doubled!!

[image]

The most obvious correction should be divide by 2, this means dividing by CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR.

I managed to make it work for all devices refactoring the code to:

```
- (void)debugGround
{
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    b2EdgeShape groundShape;
    b2FixtureDef groundFixtureDef;
    groundFixtureDef.shape = &groundShape;
    groundFixtureDef.density = 0.0;

    b2Vec2 left = b2Vec2(0, winSize.height/3/PTM_RATIO/CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR());
    b2Vec2 right = b2Vec2(winSize.width/3/PTM_RATIO/CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR(), winSize.height/3/PTM_RATIO/CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR());

    groundShape.Set(left, right);
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundFixtureDef);
}
```

I also managed to display correctly the lower platforms dividing by the scale the vertex, the offsets and anywhere I use PTM_RATIO to convert to Box2D coordinates.

It is supposed I shouldn’t use CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR by any means to multiply positions because GL functions already take this into consideration.

**Can anyone clarify this behavior? In which concepts I’m wrong?**

I hope this helps the community to understand better Box2D coordinate system.

Comment: winSize.width always gives 320x480 not 640x960 even in hd. So no need to use CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR. It works.

Comment: You are right, but it is a typo. Considering landscape mode winSize returns always 480,320 (iPhone) and 1024x768 (iPad). Then, how do you explain that Box2D coordinates takes a screem size of (10.24,7,68) on iPad non retina and (5.12,3.84) on iPad retina using the same PTM_RATIO? I KNOW I MUST NOT divide by the scale, but IT's WORKING for all devices!!! I'm just trying to understand why.

Comment: :) see for example you need point on center, then (winSize.height*0.5)/PTM_RATIO   it works for all modes...height can be 768 or 320..works for all....to add make point on 20% in x axis then put (winSize.height*0.2)/PTM_RATIO . Hope u got the point !

Comment: Yes, that is the theory. But according to the first method I posted, winSize.height/3/PTM_RATIO draws the fixture at 1/3 of the screen in non-retina, which is correct (pic 1), and winSize.height/3/PTM_RATIO is drawn at 2/3 in retina display (pic2). Box2D is multipling by 2 the coordinates somewhere, and I don't know where or why.

Comment: may be something wrong with your debug draw code....which cocos2d version you are using ? I guess its not Cocos2d 2.0...long back I observed same problem in Cocos2d 1.0...its fixed in 2.0

Comment: That is the point. I discovered that I was calling m_debugDraw = new GLESDebugDraw(PTM_RATIO * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()) because I reused the code from an old project. Creating a new project from the template the call was m_debugDraw = new GLESDebugDraw( PTM_RATIO ); That is why retina bodies were x2. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you misunderstood: GL functions (this includes ccDraw* functions!) **require** multiplication with content scale factor because GL works on pixel resolution, whereas UIKit views and cocos2d nodes use point coordinates.

Comment: But in this example we are not working at GL level. If I want to draw a line at 1/3 of the screen in points, theorically, I only need to covert from points to Box2d coordinates dividing by PTM_RATIO because cocos2d works in points and it doesn't matter if the screen is retina or not. Why dividing by PTM_RATIO doesn't work and dividing by PTM_RATIO*CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR do work?. It is the opposite I expected to behave. PTM_RATIO is 100 for both iPad types.

Comment: How did you draw the line? ccDrawLine is just a convenience function wrapping OpenGL code, so that does indeed need to be fed with pixel coordinates. I'm not sure about CCDrawNode but I suppose that should not need content scale factor applied to it. Furthermore keep in mind that you're creating a box2d vector with content scale factor applied to it, which you shouldn't do because that scales the vector *inside* the box2d world. Instead when you get the vector to draw, that's when you apply PTM_RATIO and (if needed) content scale factor.

Comment: Perhaps you need to step back for a moment. Start with a fresh project and a CCPhysicsSprite and place it at the center of the screen. You'll notice that it remains at the center regardless of Retina or iPad vs iPhone. Then try to achieve the same with a custom sprite and custom body, and apply only PTM_RATIO but no content scale factor when applying body position to sprite position. You'll notice that you get the same result on all devices. Then use -hd and -ipadhd graphics for the sprite, and you'll see other than the sprite's size nothing changes.

Comment: Also there's a simple rule to follow: **multiply** Box2D positions with PTM_RATIO before applying them to nodes, and **divide** node positions by PTM_RATIO before applying them to Box2D positions. Write a wrapper function instead of applying PTM_RATIO to every calculation to reduce the very real risk of doing this wrongly somewhere.

Comment: Maybe I forgot to say that the line is created by GLES-Debugdraw class provided by cocos2d. I tried to draw a line 1/3 of the screen to separate it from any sprite and focus in Box2D coordinates. I also created a method to drop small boxes in order to check if the debug line fits the box2d fixture. It does. I will follow your advice and start from scratch...

Comment: Sorry, not GLES.Debugdraw, I meant GLES-Render

Comment: Same difference. GLESDebugDraw is the class inside the GLES-Render.h/.m files. ;)

Comment: Done, you were right about what to do. I created a new project and everything happens as expected. The same debug code works different now. I checked the differences and I found that my old code called  m_debugDraw = new GLESDebugDraw( PTM_RATIO * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR); while the new one  m_debugDraw = new GLESDebugDraw( PTM_RATIO );
I also re-installed cocos2d 2.1 and it's templates because I felt something were wrong. Conclusion: same PTM_RATIO for iPhone devices, double it for iPads regardless the screen type, and NEVER use the scale factor. Thank you and thanks Guru.